# How to save LogCat contents to internal memory of a file?

Tags: android

I have implemented a solution

```
try {
            var process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat ${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}:V *:S")
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + "/storage/emulated/0/"+"Logging.txt")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Do we need to run this command only once or multiple times, as on Android 11 Chromebook it is working fine when run once, and on Android 10 Tablet it stops writing to file when run once, when i run it again then it writes to the same file

Answer (score 0):

you have to run this snippet every time for storing all logs to file, it dumps only current logcat content. you have fixed file name so further calls are adding text to already existing file (note that this may cause duplicated lines, if only one new appeared in log, as method is storing whole output without clearing it)

Comment: So, before calling it everytime i need to clear the file and write again?

Comment: or just store under another file name, e.g. a timestamp obtained from `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of fixed `"Logging.txt"`

Comment: I need to write in single file and upload it on server

Comment: there is no way for dumping single line or listener when new log line appear. at most you can dump few files and when need to send only single one then concat these files and remove duplicated lines